# Displaying a window's user in GNU screen's hardstatus

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I'm looking for a way to display the active user for each window in a GNU screen session in its the hardstatus line.

**Example**

I have the following windows open

- `Window 0 - user1@localmachine`
- `Window 1 - user1@localmachine`
- `Window 2 - user1@localmachine SSH to user2@remotemachine`

At the moment the hardstatus is:

```
0$ something [user1]    1$ something [user1]    2$ something [user2]
```

Where `something [username]` is typed in manually.

Is there any way to automatically display the windows current user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an escape sequence to set the window title, if that's what you want:

```
echo -e '\033k'$USER@$HOSTNAME'\033\\'
```

Just add this line to your `.bashrc` or similar file.

Comment: I don't think this line can added to .screenrc. It doesn't seem to recognise $USER.

Comment: @Ionis: `.screenrc` is not a script, it is a config file. I did not recomend .screenrc, but .bashrc - the echo does nothing if it is not run from screen.

Comment: I understand now, cheers. I thought the windows title in screen were internal. This answer is half way there, unfortunately it does not update the window title when the user changes. Is there any way to achieve this dynamic behaviour?

Comment: @Ionis: add the line to `.bashrc` of all the users.